# Matlab Interpolating Curve approximation

Tags: matlab

I have been assigned a task to get a Lagrange interpolating curve from a set of 7 points, and the value of the function at a certain X
the second part is trivial however nobody knows how to get the coefficients of the curve itself. 
here is the code I used:

```
clear
clc
x=[0 6 10 13 17 20 28];
y=[6 17 42 37 30 29 27];
m=15;
n=length(x);
  for i=1:n
        l(i)=1;
        for j=1:n
            if i~=j
            l(i)=l(i)*(m-x(j))/(x(i)-x(j));
      end
      final(i)=l(i)*y(i);
    end
    answer=sum(final);
    end
```

I cannot use interp1 for the assignment.

Is there any way to do this in matlab? I've been searching for a solution for hours but it seems like no one has ever attempted this yet.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you looking for? A analytical solution or a numerical solution? You already have a numerical solution in your code.

Comment: I have the value of y for x=12, however I need the coefficients of the polynomial Ax^6+Bx^5+Cx^4....etc

Thanks!

Comment: I found ["Lagrange Polynomial"](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26724-lagrange-polynomial) on Matlab Central. I don't see any use of `interp1` in it.

Comment: The first section of [this](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/kees/files/LagrangePolynomials.pdf) PDF, shows how to solve the coefficient matrix using linear algebra.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the coefficients, I learned how to do matrix alebra for systems of equations with LU factorization and gaussian elim but it doesn't seem to apply to this problem.

Comment: You have `x0...x6` and `y0...y6` and thus you can construct the `M` matrix and `Y` matrix. You can calculate the coefficient matrix `A = M\Y` in Matlab.

Comment: wow it's really that simple?
A=[0 6 10 13 17 20 28];
B=[6 17 42 37 30 29 27];

B\A

Comment: Unless you are not allowed to invert a matrix in Matlab, I don't see why this will not work.

Comment: I can, I'm testing it out now, thank you so much sir!

Comment: `M` is a square matrix made up of powers of `x` as given in the PDF that I linked to. `Y = B'` i.e. transpose of B. You need to do 'M\Y' not 'B\A'.

Comment: M=[0 6^2 10^3 13^4 17^5 20^6 28^7];
Y=[6 17 42 37 30 29 27];

M'\Y

gives a crazy answer....i give up lol

Comment: "nobody knows how to get the coefficients of the curve itself". For a given point, the coefficients acting on the known data (`y`) of the Lagrange formulation are the values of the basis polynomials (`l(i)`). Since coefficients independent of data give a [complicated evaluation relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Barycentric_form), for variable evaluation points (variable `m`), coefficients are best found by expanding the Lagrange basis into the monomial basis and using those multipliers. This can easily be done with `polyfit`: `c = polyfit(x,y,length(x));`